# Сравнение int64_t с int64_t возвращает 0, когда ожидается 1

Tags: c

Я пытаюсь написать простую функцию, которая находит минимум в массиве:

```
int64_t *array_int_min(int64_t *array, size_t size)
{

    int64_t mx = 2;
    mx = (mx << 63) - 2;
    int64_t *mx_pointer = NULL;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (*(array + i) <= mx)
        {
            mx = *(array + i);
            mx_pointer = array + i;
        }
    }

    return mx_pointer;
}
```

И вызываю ее, например, так:

```
int64_t arr[5] = {2, 2, 10, 1, 5};
int64_t *m_p = array_int_min(arr, 5);
```

Она, неожиданно, возвращает NULL. Я подцепил отладчик и обнаружил, что условие

```
(*(array + i) <= mx)
```

всегда возвращает ноль. Я искренне не понимаю, почему так происходит:

```
=> mx
0xfffffffffffffffe
=> *(array + i)
0x2
=> 0x2 <= 0xfffffffffffffffe
0x1
=> *(array + i) <= mx
0x0
```

Число в массиве явно меньше числа в переменной mx, но проверка все равно проваливается. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `0xfffffffffffffffe` в переводе на человеческий это -2 (вспоминаем, что старший бит в [дополнительном коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) отвечает за знак числа, а он здесь установлен, значит число отрицательное), которое очевидно меньше чем 2 и тем самым проваливает проверку

Comment: С какой призрачной целью вы делаете это настолько странным способом? 
int64_t mx = 2;
mx = (mx << 63) - 2;
- я так понимаю, это кустарный способ найти самое-самое большое целое?

Comment: @gbg да, все так

Comment: @andreymal но тогда почему в gdb 0x2 < 0xfffffffffffffffe возвращает 0x1?

Comment: @biryulin04 я в gdb не разбираюсь, но возможно потому что он сравнивает не int64_t, а uint64_t?

Comment: Для этого есть макросы https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Comment: Ну и в целом, можно в качестве затравочного просто взять первый элемент массива, а поиск начать со второго

Answer (score 0):

Как указали в комментариях, проблема была в переполнении.

```
int64_t mx = INT64_MAX;
```

Решает проблему.